# css: strange and confused layout of li element in the horizontal direction

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-lists

In my application, I came across an issue and reproduced it with the following demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ftZSl0Cv6GY7WbaMMlhv?p=preview

I used `ng-repeat` in angular to generate several `<li>` element inside the `<ul>` element. And in each `<li>` the structure is as following:

```
<ul class="articlelist">
  <li class="articleitem" ng-repeat="eacharticle in main.articlelist">
    <p class="article-title ellipsis-threelines-new">{{eacharticle.title}}</p>
    <img class="lead-image" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    <div><a>www.abc.com</a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

there is a `p`, `img` and `div` element in the sublevel

And the style for `li` element is as following, simply set them as `inline-block` element, so them will stack horizontally.

```
.articlelist {
  list-style:none;
}

.articleitem {
display: inline-block;
width:25%;
background: white;
border: 1px solid rgb(220,220,224);
height:280px;
}

.lead-image {
width:100%;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
height: 50%;
}

.article-title {
font-size:19px;
color: #313131;
padding:10px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-family: serif; 
margin: 0;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I set fixed height for each `li` element to 280px. And the content of `p` is various one by one. So the height of p is different as well. The final result is like following:
[image]

this is exactly what I got in my real application. I am very confused of why the element are aligned in this way. My desired effect is each `li` is stack in the same horizontal level with same height. The relative position of sublevel element can change based on the length of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `vertical-align:top` on `li` because `inline-block` is by default `vertical-align: baseline`

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var self = this;
  this.articlelist = [];

  this.addItem = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      var temp = {};
      temp.title = self.generateTitle(i);
      self.articlelist.push(temp);
    }
  };

  this.generateTitle = function(counter) {
    var title = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < counter * 5; i++) {
      title = title + "A";
    }
    return title;
  };
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.articlelist {
  list-style: none;
}
.articleitem {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 224);
  height: 280px;
}
.lead-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  height: 50%;
}
.article-title {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #313131;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: serif;
  margin: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.7"></script>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">        
    <button ng-click="main.addItem()">Add New One</button>
    <ul class="articlelist">
      <li class="articleitem" ng-repeat="eacharticle in main.articlelist">
        <p class="article-title ellipsis-threelines-new">{{eacharticle.title}}</p>
        <img class="lead-image" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
        <div><a>www.abc.com</a></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```